# Advice for Node.js and CouchDb Application Structure

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I'm trying to build a simple web application using Node.js and CouchDb.

The application will store tweets from Twitter's Streaming API into a CouchDb database and then feed these back into a web application real time.

At the moment I have created a simple Node.js script which can store the tweets into a database and I can have this run in the background, however, I'm stuck on how to feed back the results to users.

Should I have this (the feeding of tweets to end users) sit in a separate script which also run in the background? Or should I bundle this up with my current script?, if so how would this look (pseudo)?

I'm new to Node.js so some guidelines on the best way to do this would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't the stream backwards be fed from COuchDB's continuous or triggered _changes [notifications](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html)?

Regarding CouchDB's http api, I think it is not mandatory to put node.js between this, until node.js has other tasks like filtering or is acting as a security layer?

Comment: Thanks for that input. I think my best approach would be to have the Node.js capturing the twitter data in the background while I use CouchDb / CouchApp to create an application (utlising _changes) to display the results.

Comment: Would be glad to hear about the result or see some code, if it's to become open source:)

Comment: chris polzer : Have put this on hold, but will recomment with a link when I'm done :)